# javascript hash tag linking

Tags: javascript, jquery, deep-linking

I'm trying to modify this porfolio script here: http://themes.iki-bir.com/webpaint/multipage/full/portfolio.html

It uses urls like `#entry-12` (using the index number of the element to deeplink the item) and I'd like to change it to `#this-is-an-item`

```
updateURLParameter(thumb.attr("data-event-id"));
//updateURLParameter("entry-"+thumb.index());
```

It sets the name here (which works fine)... now it's whatever.html#this-is-an-item

But now I need to change the behaviour when they link in from the URL (as it no longer works since it's still looking for the index number instead of a name).

```
     var deeplink = getUrlVars("#");

 // DEEPLINK START IF NECESSARY
     if (deeplink[0].split('entry-').length>1) {
        var thmb = parseInt(deeplink[0].split('entry-')[1],0)+1;
         $container.find('.item:nth-child('+thmb+')').click();
         $container.find('.item:nth-child('+thmb+')').addClass("active").children('a').children('div').fadeIn(300);;

    }
```

I'm just not sure how to do the last part, so it looks for the data-event-id instead of the index?

```
<li class="item installation 2013-10-13" data-event-id="installation-opening-whispering-in-the-leaves"... </li>
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML for `$container`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var deeplink = getUrlVars("#");
var $elem;
//         v--- this can be changed to .find('.item) if needed.
$container.children('.item').each(function() {
    // you can use .data(...) instead of .attr("data-...") 
    if ($(this).data("event-id") == deeplink[0])
        $elem = $(this);
});
if ($elem) {
   $elem.click()
        .addClass("active")
        .children('a')
        .children('div')
        .fadeIn(300);
}
```

Simply iterate over all the elements in `$container` with the class `.item`, and check if the `data-event-id` matches the one in the URL hash. If it does, store it, and do your operations afterwards.